# Python Pandas aggregate the data

Tags: python

```
    import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('txn.csv')
print(df)

#printing the data

     Date                   debit           credit
0  01-12-2019             100.00           0.00
1  05-12-2019             200.00       500.00
2  01-12-2019             105.00       200.00
3  05-12-2019               10.00       100.00
```

I would like to print the aggregate data ie., sum of debit, credit as mentioned below.

```
Date                    debit           credit
01-12-2019             205.00        200.00
05-12-2019             210.00       600.00
```

> Could any suggest

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

see documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `groupby()` function. So with your current dataframe:

```
aggregated = df.groupby('Date').agg({'debit':'sum','credit':'sum'})
```